# Texmaker - nested document structure

Tags: texmaker, input, nesting, ide

Let's say I have a file that inputs files who input files.

foo.tex: `\input{bar}`

bar.tex: `\input{baz}`

baz.tex: `Hello World!`

When I am in `foo.tex`, Texmaker shows the structure

```
foo    
--- bar
```

When I am in `bar.tex`, it shows

```
bar   
--- baz
```

When I am in `baz.tex`, it only shows

```
baz
```

Any way to make it always display

```
foo    
---bar    
------baz
```

instead?

**Edit:**
Or if there is not, is there a latex editor that does support this?

Answer (score 1):

Sort answer: No (afaik). TeXmaker  simply read `\input{bar}` and  then make a clickable "bar" label to open `bar.tex`, but the program do not  make a recursive search, if fact do not check if the child file really exist.

Ask to see the hierarchy opening the child file (`bar.tex`) is simply ask too munch, IMHO. There are no any information in `bar.tex` about foo.tex, how the program can suppose that is a child file? Check in all the files of the working directory for a \input{bar}? And what if the file main file is not here? Search in all the hard disk? This really can slow down the computer.  And what if `bar.tex` is included in both `foo.tex` and `puf.tex` and ten more files? What "main" document must be shown then?

The best could be start the child files like  `bar.tex` with a comment like `% included in foo.tex` so you will not need this feature.